# mule 4.4 community edition - parsing file read as stream

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

This question is a follow up to my earlier question [here][1]
Thanks to @aled I am using 'set-payload' with expression.

Am reading a file and trying to parse and then validate each row.
Edit2 : added File details below : ( I need to validate that each row of the file has a price value , in below example line item 'Butter' has no price so should be flagged as an error while the other rows are good and they should be sent as a POST request to a third party api

```
d1|Milk|3.9|
d2|Butter||
g1|Bread|1.6|
g2|Biscuits|3.4|
d3|Yogurt|5.5|
d4|Flavored Yogurt|5.5|
m1|Toothbrush|12|
```

File reading is a repeatable-in-memory-stream
Now after reading the file , am setting the payload using 'set-payload'.
Here is the complete code of this flow :

```
<flow name="get:shoppingProducts" >
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="get list of products request received "/>
    <file:read doc:name="Read file"  config-ref="File_Config" path="/product_master/test.unl" outputMimeType='application/csv; header=false; separator=|' outputEncoding="utf-8">
        <repeatable-in-memory-stream />
    </file:read>
    <choice doc:name="is the file empty ?" >
        <when expression="sizeOf(payload) == 0">
            <logger level="ERROR" doc:name="Payload is empty " message="Empty payload from File read !"/>
            <raise-error doc:name="Raise error on empty file " type="XYZ:EMPTY" description="Empty file"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise >
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Payload not empty"  message="All good"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>

    <set-payload value="#[output application/json

    ---

    payload map (value,index)->
    {
      id:value.column_0,
      description:value.column_1,
      price:value.column_2

     }]" doc:name="Set Payload" mimeType="application/json" encoding="UTF-8"  />

    <foreach doc:name="For Each file record" collection="#[payload]">
        <logger level="DEBUG" doc:name="Log record" message="#[payload.description]"/>
        <scripting:execute doc:name="Validate data" engine="Groovy">
            <scripting:code ><![CDATA[println("hello world 001");
            println(payload);
            println("hello world 002");
            println(message.getPayload());
            println("hello world 003");
            println(payload.description);]]></scripting:code>
        </scripting:execute>
    </foreach>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"  message="after reading products file  "/>
```

This seems to work fine and I can see payload like below ( after calling set-payload ) :

```
[
  {
    "id": "d1",
    "description": "Milk",
    "price": 3.9
  },
  {
    "id": "d2",
    "description": "Butter",
    "price": 4.5
  },
  ...
]
```

Now I am trying to iterate over the data in a for loop
First component in the for loop is a 'Logger' which is logging the payloads description:

```
<logger level="DEBUG" doc:name="Log record" message="hello we are here #[payload.description]"/>
```

This is showing up fine in logs:

> hello we are here "Milk"

( I am running code in debug mode ) and now the minute control reaches my groovy script inside the for loop , things go wrong ...
In debug the payload still shows up correctly as :

```
{
  "id": "d1",
  "description": "Milk",
  "price": "3.9"
}
```

However when I try and access one of its attributes in groovy script am getting this error:

> "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: description for class: org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamDecorator"

Could this be happening because I am using 'repeatable-in-memory-stream' which is causing for loop to again get the stream rather than json payload ?

I also tried changing file read to : non-repeatable-stream but in this case my set-payload script is not able to handle :

> org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.result.AbstractReturnDelegate$ConnectedInputStreamWrapper@70ee7444

What am I doing wrong and how to correct this please?

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. For Mule flows specifically the image doesn't provide any insight nor details. Instead copy the XML of the entire flow. Where are you seeing the streams? In the debugger? What is the log actually showing? Please add the full text of the log. Where do you see the payload being empty exactly and at which step of the flow?

Comment: thanks @aled , updated question with complete code of the flow , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your groovy script. You are assuming the objects are a specific Java class and trying to access it directly. In some cases it may be true but you can not make assumptions. It also completely unneeded since Mule 4 & DataWeave provide a direct alternative to what you are trying to do (ir a logger component). Mule 4 is designed for users to avoid having to resort to Java or Groovy for normal tasks.

In your updated comments and question you made it clear that you need to validate that the price field is not null. That is a very basic validation and there is absolutely no need to go the Groovy/Java route for that. You can add a choice router inside the foreach loop with condition `isEmpty(payload.price)` to validate if the price is null, empty or spaces (since it is a string spaces is a valid check). Mule built-in components know to handle payloads that are contained in a stream transparently you don't even need to bother about handling streams.

Comment: thanks @aled , but my issue is that its a community edition of Mule runtime 4.4 , so I cannot really use Transform ( Dataweave ) , so how do I go about validating the payload and then later ultimately using this payload to call a REST endpoint downstream ?

Comment: It doesn't look like you provide that context in your question. It will depend on how are you trying to validate. You can use the HTTP Request connector to use the payload. Perhaps you should focus your question on what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks @aled , so we are using community edition of mule runtime 4.4 , we need to read and parse pipe delimited files , validate each line and then make a rest ( POST ) call to a third party api . Presently I am stuck since the file read operation is generating a Stream and without Transform component , I am unable to parse and validate the payload . To add - have added dataweave script inside setPayload component to generate application/json , but when I run a for each loop , the data is again back to a Stream...  thank you

Comment: and to add I am trying to validate each line of the file in a Groovy script

Comment: Note that you still didn't explain in detail what validation logic you are trying to implement. It is difficult to provide suggestions if we don't understand what are you trying to do. Mule HTTP Requester is perfectly capable of parsing streams. It seems that the only holdout is the validation.

Comment: thanks @aled for your patience , I have added an example of the file I need to parse and the validation I need to perform ( null check for now ) , the additional business requirements are being elaborated and will definitely be more involved but to start with this is one check I need to do if I can parse the data within stream , thank you